# Hotspot not working ubuntu 19.10

Tags: 19.10

In `nm-connection-editor` if I use `mode = Hotspot`, hotspot doesn't start and nothing happens. But when I use `mode =`Ad-hoc` it works fine. 
I tried the classic steps of creating the hotspot, they don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating a hotspot for the first time, a file called `Hotspot` is created in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`, which holds configuration settings. So make sure to create a hotspot first, or else this file will not be present. Edit the configuration file with a text editor, for example, `nano` using the command:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot
```

Configure the network SSID, password and other settings.

After making changes to the Hotspot file, save it by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> 
After making changes to the hotspot configuration file you'll need to restart Network Manager:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```